# Setting up NAT forwarding using iptables on ubuntu server 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, iptables, nat

I have a server with 2 ethernet interfaces(em1 and em2). em1 is the internet facing interface(192.168.16.113) and em2 has a static address(10.1.1.100) connected to a switch. I have configured the gateway and dns nameservers for em2 to be that of em1(192.168.1.1). I want the systems connected behind the switch(all have ip addresses in 10.1.1.101 - 10.1.1.149) to have access to the internet via the server. I configured nat on the server using iptables as follows

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o em1 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i em1 -o em2 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i em2 -o em1 -j ACCEPT
```

I also configured the nameserver and dns of the system behind the switch to be 10.1.1.100. However when i `ping google.com` from behind the switch, **the name is resolved** but i dont get any response from the outside network. Can somebody please help me ?

**I also want to mention that i can ping the server from behind the switch. I can also access the internet from the server.**

I would also like to know how to save the configuration so that it is loaded on startup.

Edit: I have uncommented `net.ipv4.ip forward=1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`

Comment: Saving your configuration, if it's all `iptables`, will be easy - use the `iptables-persistent` package.

Comment: what do you get for `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`? It needs to be 1. While a lot of people do, I don't use `iptables-persistent`. I just call my iptables script from my `/etc/network/interfaces` file with a pre-up directive, i.e. `pre-up /home/doug/init/doug_firewall`. Is what you have shown above your entire iptables rule set?

Comment: @DougSmythies I have enabled ipv4 forwarding..Will edit it in the question. And yes that is my entire rule set.

Comment: It is not obvious what is wrong. Could you add the output from `sudo iptables -v -x -n -L` and `sudo iptables -t nat -v -x -n -L` to your question. Do the commands after trying to access internet from a client, so that we can observe the packet counter values. It might be time to use tcpdump (or wireshark, if you prefer) to observe what is going on at the packet level.

Comment: @DougSmythies Problem solved after i flushed all the tables and added just nat entry. wierd....